# Installing OpenSAGE.BlenderPlugin addon does nothing

Tags: add-on

I'm trying to install OpenSAGE.BlenderPlugin addon. I'm using Blender 2.93.4 , supposedly it works from version 2.81 on. I go to Blender Preferences, click on install and select OpenSAGE.BlenderPlugin-master.zip but nothing happens. The installing the plugin section of the plugin says to select io_mesh_w3d-X.X.zip to install it, but I dont see that file anywhere, only a io_mesh_w3d folder.

Anyone used this plugin and knows how to install it?

Answer (score 0):

The [instructions from their repository](https://github.com/OpenSAGE/OpenSAGE.BlenderPlugin/wiki/Installing-the-Plugin) state that you need to download the zip file from the release page and not to download a copy of the repository's master branch.

> Next you need to download the latest plugin version from the releases page: https://github.com/OpenSAGE/OpenSAGE.BlenderPlugin/releases
>
> **NOTE:** Do **NOT** use the **'Clone or download'** option since this downloaded .zip file will not install properly in Blender due to an invalid folder structure and naming!

Therefore, you need to download the `io_mesh_w3d.zip` as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: Correct file]

Comment: I didnt understand what they meant, but now I see there are 2 links with files to download. Thanks.